# Memoization of this leetcode problem. How do I memoize this recursive solution

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have made all possible swipes and then at the end I have passed the array to be checked if it is increasing or not.
this is the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-swaps-to-make-sequences-increasing) and I have written the recursive approach as follows

```java
class Solution {
    public int minSwap(int[] A, int[] B) {
        
        return helper(A,B,0,0);
    }
    
    boolean helper2(int[] A,int[] B){
        
        for(int i=0;i<A.length-1;i++){
           if(A[i]>=A[i+1] || B[i]>=B[i+1])
               return false;
        }
        return true;
        
    }
    
    int helper(int[] A,int[] B,int i,int swaps){
        if(i==A.length && helper2(A,B)==true)
            return swaps;
        if(i==A.length)
            return 1000;
       
        
        swap(A,B,i);
       int c=helper(A,B,i+1,swaps+1);
        swap(A,B,i);
        int b=helper(A,B,i+1,swaps);
        
        
      return Math.min(b,c); 
    }
    private void swap(int[] A, int[] B, int index){
        int temp = A[index];
        A[index] = B[index];
        B[index] = temp;
    }
    
}
```

Here I have tried all possible swipes and then checked them and returned one with minimum swipes. How do I do memoization of this. Which variables should I use in memoization of this code. Is there any thumb rule of selecting variables for memoization?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) says:

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by **storing the results** of expensive function calls and **returning the cached result** when the **same inputs occur** again.

Since `A` and `B` don't change, the inputs are `i` and `swaps`, so for every combination of the two, we need to store the result.

One way to do this, is to use a `HashMap` with a key with the 2 values, e.g.

```java
class Key {
    int i;
    int swaps;
    // implement methods, especially equals() and hashCode()
}
```

You can then add the following at the beginning of `helper()`, though you might want to add it after the two `if` statements:

```java
Key key = new Key(i, swap);
Integer cachedResult = cache.get(key);
if (cachedResult != null)
    return cachedResult;
```

Then replace the `return` statement with:

```java
int result = Math.min(b,c);
cache.put(key, result);
return result;
```

Whether `cache` is a field or a parameter being passed along is entirely up to you.